# Binary Tree Max Path Sum: Faulty Logic

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to solve a problem of finding Binary Tree Max path sum. I will post the problem statement.

> Write a function that takes in a Binary Tree and returns its max path sum. A path is a collection of connected nodes in a tree, where no node is connected to more than two other nodes; a path sum is
> the sum of the values of the nodes in a particular path. Each BinaryTree node has an integer value a left child node, and a right child node. Children nodes can either be
> BinaryTree nodes themselves or None / null.

I need help trying to solve this problem. I have few thoughts, but I am not close to drafting a solution or logic isn't translating to code directly.

Answers that can possibly be max path sum in the iteration

- root alone
- root alone with a left max path
- root alone with a right max path
- some double path/triangle in the left subtree
- some double path/triangle in the right subtree

so there are two types of situations:

- **attachablePath** (the type of path where i can add root node and compare if its bigger sum or not)
- **unattachablePath** (the type of path that is a triangular path with root as one of the children in subtree)

and i think i need to have a function that returns both so that the root node that calls them can decide
which is more beneficial to them
now we probably compare and figure out both options

```
    bestAttachable = max of leftattachablePath + root, rightAttachablePath + root
    bestUnattachable = max of leftUnattachable, rightUnattachable, root, leftattachable + root + unattachable.
```

does that make sense?
Please help me think about this the right way. I feel like i am missing some things that could possibly go wrong. or unsure
how to translate logic to code effectively.

I tried this

```
def maxPathSum(tree):
    # Write your code here.
    maxA, maxB = helper(tree)
 #   print(maxA, maxB)
    return max(maxA, maxB)
    pass


def helper(node):
    if node is None:
        return 0, float("-inf")
    left_attachable, left_unattachable = helper(node.left)
    right_attachable, right_unattachable = helper(node.right)

#    print('left is ', left_attachable, ' right is ', right_attachable)
    max_attachable = max( left_attachable+node.value, right_attachable+node.value, node.value)
    print(node.value, left_unattachable, right_unattachable, left_attachable, right_attachable)
    max_unattachable = max(left_unattachable, right_unattachable, left_attachable+node.value+right_attachable, node.value)

    return max_attachable, max_unattachable
```

but this fails during the cases where right_attachable or left_attachable are the maximum ones. Also, i have set the base case of attachable to be 0 but when tree has all negative nodes, then max is the least of all nodes but not 0 but I can't set -inf to attachable too, because when I attach nodes to it, it should be the magnitude of node values.

Comment: What's the answer for a tree with one node only (root) with value `-1`?

Comment: I think it should be -1 but my code will return 0 because of the base case and thats one of the problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The following is untested.) It seems to me that we need a wrapper method, as you indicated, since the main method returns only one value and we can't distinguish from that if it refers to a path segment not reachable from the current node. Something like:

```
f(tree):
  max_attachable, max_unattachable = g(tree)

  return max(
    max_attachable,
    max_unattachable
  )
```

For the helper method, if we're at any one node, couldn't the solution be

```
if node is null:
  return -Infinity, -Infinity

l_attachable, l_unattachable = g(node.left)
r_attachable, r_unattachable = g(node.right)

max_attachable = max(
  node.value,
  l_attachable + node.value,
  node.value + r_attachable
)

max_unattachable = max(
  l_attachable + node.value + r_attachable,
  l_attachable,
  r_attachable,
  l_unattachable,
  r_unattachable
)

return max_attachable, max_unattachable
```

?

Comment: well first issue i see is that

Comment: well first issue i see is that
1) your max attachable cant have 'l_attachable + node.value + r_attachable' because you are a triangular path now which cant be attached any further
2) max_unattachable can't have just node.value? i am kinda confused about that too. also for me max_unattachable should also include l_attachable + node.value + r_attachable.

Also, we are missing the case when l_attachable alone is the max path sum, we don't account for it all. I am stuck on the same problems.

Comment: @Karina ah, good point about `l_attachable + node.value + r_attachable` -- removed.

Comment: @Karina and good point about `l/r_attachable` as candidates -- added them to `max_unattachable`. I don't understand your question `"max_unattachable can't have just node.value?"` -- node.value *is* attachable.

Comment: @Karina can you share the link to the online judge?

Comment: @Karina I added `l_attachable + node.value + r_attachable` to `max_unattachable` (first I removed it but just realised it should be a candidate). Looks good to me as a whole now. Can you try it on the judge?

Comment: give me a moment let me try.

Comment: it actually passes, what...

Comment: @Karina great! Do you have more questions about it?

Comment: no thank you for helping me, i am working on another problem now. I will accept the answer, I didn't know i was 2 cases away from solving it. thank you for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

You must keep both. The bottom-up approach logic if that a node should know:

- the best attachable path including itself - meaning itself and the best linear path starting either from the right of the left
- the current best path either attachable or not.

The good news when you go that way, is that it is easy to compute those paths for a parent node when they are known for both of its children

And when you finally reach the root, you have the answer...

Comment: but if i include best attachable and best unattachable path, wouldn't that cover all cases? why does the pair have to be best attachable + current best path either way. wouldnt the best part either way be redundant since we store best attachable anyway?

Comment: The pair can of course be best attachable and best unattachable. Simply if the best attachable is better than the best unattachable, the latter is useless anyway...

Comment: if there is best attachable, best curr path, wouldn't it forget to get the best unattachable (if the best in the moment is attachable)? since it might be needed later in case your higher/parent node is negative? why would you say its useless? i am intrigued.